# How to wait a thread in ajax/js until user selects a file during file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the code and it'll help you understand the problem better.
HTML Code:-

```
{{#each uploadsData as |row|}}
  <div {{action 'upload' row uploadsData}} class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--hide-phone kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid_icon">
      {{inline-svg row.svg}}
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell--10-col  mdl-cell--12-col-phone kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid__text">
      <span class="mdl-cell--hide-desktop" style="padding: 5%;">{{inline-svg row.svg}}</span>
      <span class="kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid__text_title">{{row.heading}}</span>
      <span class="kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid__text_subText">
        {{if (eq row.optional true) "(Optional)" ""}}
      </span>
      <span class="kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid__text_select {{if (eq row.isSubmitted true) "kyc-uploads__form_uploads_documents-grid__text_select_completed" ""}}">
        <i class="material-icons">done</i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="file" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" id="{{row.key}}" name="{{row.key}}" value="{{inputFile}}" />
{{/each}}
```

JS code:-

```
upload(row, uploadsData) { 
    var el =$('#'+row.key);
    el.click();
    var file = el[0].files[0];
    console.log(file);
    if(file != null){
        //do something...
    }); 
    this.controller.set('isCompleted', completionStatus);
}
```

When user click on `el.click()` for file upload it opens a dialog box to select files.
Now here is the trick one thread automatically come out of the loop because file is not selected yet and the other one is asking user to select a file. So do you have any idea how can i wait to check if a file is null until user selects a file??

Comment: If you're looking for file upload, why are you trying to reimplement `<input type="file">` for choosing a file rather than using the `input` tag itself? That'll also avoid this issue that you're facing, You can have a callback `onChange` which will check if the file has been selected or not and then do whatever function is necessary

Comment: Thank u so much i'll try it out..

Comment: Hey! I have a doubt in your explanation. This method of yours was working when applied on static key of input field. But I realised that i am generating my filed input key dynamically so how i can implement the same function.P.S:- For code reusability i am generating file inputs dynamically. @Sudheesh Singanamalla

Comment: Can you show a sample of your code i.e. the rendered HTML and the segment rendering it. Please edit your question to have the details.

Comment: I have added html code please have a look.

Comment: For each row there's an input file item with the `id` attribute defined as `row.key`. Do you mean to say there'll be a point where a user can click and choose a file for each row and you want to upload all the chosen files? Have you tried to use `class="something"` and get all file items by class instead of `id`?

Comment: Got that! applied some hack